# Refresing a vue app gives: Cannot GET /path

Tags: javascript, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a simple webpack template vue app, and let's say I have a page with

```
http://localhost:8080/profile
```

On my local page, I can go from any page to /profile and even once on /profile I can refresh/reload the page and I get no error.

But I deployed my app on heroku and even though I can navigate from any page to any other, but if I am for example on /profile page and I hit refresh i get

```
Cannot GET /statement
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You trying to use history mode of router without backend.
For getting things working, you may use Express JS. Previous answer is not working for me and i write my own server script.
Here is the my server.js for running Vue app with history mode.
server.js (with Express):

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
```

Place this file in the root directory of your project (not src).

Run this script with Node: `node server.js`

Don't forget build your app for production ;)!

Comment: Are you sure your code works? Here is the diff, before I had my setup and after replacing yours https://i.imgur.com/xSFd14T.png now my heroku server just stopped working

Comment: Also, you have twice `app.use(staticFileMiddleware);` ... I don't think that answer is correct

Comment: there is no errors, it is working script i'm using in production many times without problems. More explains about this decision here: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/master/examples/static-files-and-index-rewrite/README.md

Comment: and check please your "start" script in package.json. My "start" script looking like this: "start": "node server.js"

Comment: Yeah, the start is okay. I am using this config now https://github.com/fedemarske/search-product/blob/e0f193ea83a606e7c29e139b51dec6b3575d3030/api/server.js it has some issues, but I think I'm close

Comment: Are you using a vuejs app with the webpack template?

Comment: Yes, sure. Build them and git push heroku master. I will try it now.

Comment: For some reason, on the second try, your code worked. I think I was missing the library `connect-history-api-fallback` even though I wrote it on package.json inside dependencies and heroku didn't install it... thanks

Comment: @VladislavGritsenko it worked and save time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think your vue-router is in HTML5 History Mode. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

In development mode, the `webpack-dev-server` handles the redirect for your but your need to configure your server used in production to redirect your routes.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, can you please provide the answer? I have four files in my config folder and I don't know which one to modify