# vue js:routes not found when page reloads

Tags: javascript, express, vuejs2, vue-router

Here is simple vue-routing

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
  const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }


  const routes = [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
  ];
  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes:routes,
    mode: 'history'
  });

  var app = new Vue({
  router,
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  mounted:function(){

  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

In **HTML**

```
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
```

The links loaded properly  (ie :`/foo` and `/bar`) when i click on it but if i refresh any vue routed url (ie `/foo` or `/bar`) url i will get error message

> cannot get the page

I am serving it with simple express server

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html',{ root : __dirname}))
```

Comment: is this happenning locally or on prod? Are you using the webpack template?  because, there are various solutions for this depending on the issue

Comment: its happening on local  i am not using webpack build everything included in index.html file and it serves with express

Comment: you need to install `connect-history-api-fallback` for the htm5 api fall back as shown and configure your express as shown here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277747/refresing-a-vue-app-gives-cannot-get-path

Comment: Hou have to point all routes to `index.html` like: `app.get('*'...`

Comment: @samayo i have installed that  connect-history-api-fallback and configured but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: use the same settings as shown there, also make sure the connect-history-api-fallback is installed for devDepdendecies as well

Comment: @samayo issue resolved i forgot add packages in package.json

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect all the routes to main file `index.html`.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html',{ root : __dirname}))
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html',{ root : __dirname}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect all the routes to main file `index.html`, but after of your route main, so:

```
//route main
app.use('/api/example', require('./routes/example')); 
//routes auxiliary
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root : __dirname + '/public'}))
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root : __dirname + '/public'}))
```